# Travelling with Récépissé de Demande de Carte de Séjour

Tags: visas, france

I arrived in France in January 2019 on VLS/TS Type D Visa (valid for 1 year). Then I also got the sticker from OFII. My visa is going to expire in October 2019, so I applied for the renewal at the local prefecture. They provided me a document which says:

**Récépissé de Demande de Carte de Séjour**

Prefecture, Name and other details

**A Demande le renouvellement de son Titre de Sejour Dont la validite expire le xx/xx/xxxx**

Ce recepisse n'est valable qu'accompagne de de titre (Visa de long sejour valant T.S.) N. xxxxxxxxxx

Il autorise son titulaire a travailler.

This récépissé will expire in 6 months. But I have to travel to India from 1 October to 31 October. During this period my Type D visa will expire. **Can I come back to France by showing my VLS/TS Type D Visa (expired) + OFII Sticker + mentioned Récépissé?**

**Edit**:

I came across this **Circulaire NOR IMIK0900087C** by the French government, is it good as proof?
[image]

Comment: I disagree with the close vote. The question *is* about travel, namely about whether a certain document is a valid travel document. It could also be viewed as being about expatriation, but the two are not necessarily mutually exclusive.

Comment: You will probably be unable to board a flight to France with those documents.

Comment: @phoog According to the Circulaire NOR IMIK0900087C, it says you can travel if its a renewal of carte de Sejour. Please have look at the edit section.

Comment: @phoog if you check the second bold line of the question, I hope it means the same. Because the heading for both cases is the same (if you are applying for the first time or renewing it). Only the content mentioned in the body tells you the difference. I followed this URL: https://thefrenchadobo.com/how-to-apply-for-a-carte-de-sejour-or-french-residency-card/ . I hope this information is correct.

Comment: @PSS part of my confusion (related to my now deleted comment) was the imprecise translation.  I thought that the *recipisse* would be useful only if you were renewing the *carte de séjour,* but actually it covers renewal of *titres de séjour.*  The latter term is broader, including as it does D visas (at least it includes D visas that are VLS-TS).

Comment: @phoog yes it includes VLS-TS. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: I am reading this a year later in a similar situation . Were you able to return to France with your Récépissé and expired visa? Thanks!

Comment: @Micah Yes, it is admissible. Just present your Récépissé + expired VISA to the officials. It will be fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to TIMATIC, the database that your airline will use to determine whether it's okay to fly you to France (and in contrast to my earlier suspicion expressed in a comment):

> - Receipts of application for Renewal of a residence permit issued by France (Recepisse de demande de carte de sejour - renouvellement de titre de sejour) are accepted if accompanied by the expired residence permit or an expired "D" visa.
> - Receipts of application for a first residence permit (Recepisse de demande de carte de sejour - delivrance d'un premier titre de sejour) are not accepted.

Since your *recipisse* indicates that it is a renewal, you should be okay.